# Elements of order $p$ in $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

I have a question about an exercise from Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups book. Let $p \neq 2$ a prime number with the property that
$2$ modulo $p$ is *not* a square. We going to study the finite
group $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p) \cong 
\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)/ \pm I_2$.

Let $\overline{A} \in \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be any element of
order $p$, ie $(\overline{A})^p= I_2$ in $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Claim: $\overline{A}$ has a representant $A$ in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$
which has an eigenvalue $\lambda_A=1$.

I not know how to prove it. By definition, every
$\overline{A} \in \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has two
possible representants: $A= A \cdot I$ and $-A= A \cdot (-I_2) \in 
\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Let study $A= \left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)$.
Then $ad-bc=det(A)=1$ since it lives in $SL_2$.

Passing to algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ in corresponding $\operatorname{SL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ matix
$A$ may have two possible characteristic polynomials $P_A(X)$ (if we exclude the tedious case that $A$ is a scalar matrix):

$$ P_A(X)= (X-r)^2 \text{ or } (X-s) \cdot (X-t)  $$

with $r, s, t\in \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ such that $s \neq t$. If $P_A(X)= (X-r)^2$,
we conclude $r^2= det(A)=1$, so $r= \pm 1$. If $r=1$ we are done, if
$r=-1$, we pass to other representant $-A$ and are also done.

I cannot show that case $P_A(X)=(X-s) \cdot (X-t) $ never happens here.
Since $A^p= \pm I_2$ we get $s^p= \pm 1$ and $t^p= \pm 1$. Why this
leads to a contradiction? That means, why case
$P_A(X)=(X-s) \cdot (X-t) $ can't happen in this context?

Comment: $P_A(A)=0$ but $P_A(A^p)=(P_A(A))^p = 0$ too. Since $A^p=\pm I_2$, that gives you the result about $r,s,t$ you want. Here we use that $M \mapsto M^p$ is an automorphism of the ring generated by $A$, since that is a commutative ring in which $p=0$.

Comment: similar idea, different wording: if $s^p = 1$ then using the Frobenius map:  $(s-1)^p = s^p +(-1)^p=s^p - 1=1-1 = 0\implies (s-1) =0\implies s = 1$ .  Virtually identical for $s^p = -1$

Comment: right, the Frobenuis action extends to the ring of polynomials! Thank you two and shame on me ;-)